# d3.js and d3.tile | Zoom parameter

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

Working in Angular, I am trying to implement a zoom on my tiles from OpenStreetMap.
This is how I build them :

```
this.projection = d3.geoMercator()
      .scale(125)
      .center([0, 20])
      .translate([element.offsetWidth / 2, element.offsetHeight / 2]);

    const pi = Math.PI, tau = 2 * pi;

    this.tiles = d3Tile.tile()
      .size([element.offsetWidth, element.offsetHeight])
      .scale(this.projection.scale() * tau)
      .translate(this.projection([0, 0]))();

svg.selectAll('image')
      .data(this.tiles)
      .enter().append("image")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "http://" + "abc"[d[1] % 3] + ".tile.openstreetmap.org/" + d[2] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[1] + ".png"; })
      .attr("x", (d) => { return (d[0] + this.tiles.translate[0]) * this.tiles.scale; })
      .attr("y", (d) => { return (d[1] + this.tiles.translate[1]) * this.tiles.scale; })
      .attr("width", this.tiles.scale)
      .attr("height", this.tiles.scale);
```

This works as expected.
I am now trying to zoom those tiles when I do zoom the rest :

```
   this.zoom = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1, 10])
        .on('zoom', (d) => this.handleZoom(d));
      d3.select('svg').call(this.zoom);
```

I am now struggling to find the parameters that I need to zoom on them. I understand the process of retrieving the image, the x/y/z, but struggle finding the values I should put in my scale and translate parameters.

I would like to do something as simple as :

```
handleZoom(event) {

const transform = event.transform;
 const element = this.mapContainer.nativeElement;

  const newProjection = d3.geoMercator()
      .scale(transform.k * 125)
      .center([0, 20])
      .translate([element.offsetWidth / 2, element.offsetHeight / 2]);

    // Update tiles
    this.tiles = d3Tile.tile()
      .size([element.offsetWidth, element.offsetHeight])
      .scale(newProjection.scale() * 2 * Math.PI)
      .translate(newProjection([0, 0]))();
    

d3.select('svg')
      .selectAll('image')
      .data(this.tiles)
      .join('image')
      [...same code as before]
}
```

But obvisously, my values here are wrong. Could someone help me finding what I get wrong ?